# Trying to extend LifecycleService to my JobIntentService so I can observe LivaData, but can only have one class appear in the supertype list

Tags: android, android-service, android-lifecycle, android-livedata, intentservice

SO I am trying to observe some LiveData in my repository, so I can work with this data and update it's items according to my operations. But I can't figure out how to access the data. When I try to observe it, the ~Observer`is asking for a LifecycleOwner. Reading about similar problems I've seen a suggestion to extend`LifecycleService`, but when I do I get the error saying`Only one class may appear in a supertype list`.
How do I go around this?

This is my service:

```
class DetectJobIntentService : JobIntentService() {

    private val TAG = "DetectJobIntentServi22"

    fun enqueueWork(context: Context, work: Intent) {
        enqueueWork(context, DetectJobIntentService::class.java, 12, work)
    }

    override fun onHandleWork(intent: Intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onHandleWork")

        val options = FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
            .setClassificationMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ACCURATE)
            .setClassificationMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ALL_CLASSIFICATIONS)
            .setMinFaceSize(0.15f)
            .build()

        val detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance()
            .getVisionFaceDetector(options)

        val repo = PhotoRepository(application)
        val allPhotos = repo.getAllPhotos()
        allPhotos.observe(SomeLifeCycleOwner, Observer {
            for (file in it) {
                val image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromFilePath(application, Uri.parse(file.uri))

                detector.detectInImage(image).addOnSuccessListener { list ->
                    if (list.isNotEmpty()) {
                        file.hasFaces = 1
                        repo.update(file)
                    } else {
                        file.hasFaces = 2
                        repo.update(file)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

EDIT: Following Sina's suggestion which sounds right, I've tried implementing a query that fetches the data into a non-LiveData object my app crashes.

This is the quesry I've added in my Dow:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM photos_table")
fun getAllPhotosStatic(): MutableList<Photo>
```

If I run at at this point it's all good.

Then in my repository I've added this:

```
val allPhotosStatic = photoDao.getAllPhotosStatic()
```

And as soon as I've done that and try to run the app it crashes, and I get this stack:

```
2019-11-13 23:49:37.079 20720-20720/tech.levanter.anyvision E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: tech.levanter.anyvision, PID: 20720
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tech.levanter.anyvision/tech.levanter.anyvision.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class tech.levanter.anyvision.viewModels.AllPhotosViewModel
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2991)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3126)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1846)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6882)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class tech.levanter.anyvision.viewModels.AllPhotosViewModel
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:238)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:164)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:130)
        at tech.levanter.anyvision.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:66)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7232)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7221)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2971)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3126) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1846) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6882) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:230)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:164) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:130) 
        at tech.levanter.anyvision.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:66) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7232) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7221) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2971) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3126) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1846) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6882) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873) 
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotMainThread(RoomDatabase.java:267)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:323)
        at androidx.room.util.DBUtil.query(DBUtil.java:83)
        at tech.levanter.anyvision.room.PhotoDao_Impl.getAllPhotosStatic(PhotoDao_Impl.java:154)
        at tech.levanter.anyvision.room.PhotoRepository.<init>(PhotoRepository.kt:37)
        at tech.levanter.anyvision.viewModels.AllPhotosViewModel.<init>(AllPhotosViewModel.kt:12)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:230) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:164) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:130) 
        at tech.levanter.anyvision.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:66) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7232) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7221) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2971) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3126) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1846) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6882) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

I thought maybe I can just get a copy of the data into a static list in my repository, but for that I'd need to observe it in the repository and I'm stuck at the same place again because I don't have a lifecycleOwner.

Comment: You could observe the `LiveData` forever, and in the `onStop` of the service unregister the observer. But anyway: if I'm not mistaken the `JobIntentService` will complete and stop after the `onHandleWork` returns anyway. Use a `Service` (not an `IntentService`) if you need to do async work.

Comment: @MarkusPenguin I have no issue with unregistering the Observer after onStop. I just need it for the duration of my operations. But I can't observe it, that my whole issue.

Comment: @MarkusPenguin didn't know ObserveForever was a class! I tried to implement it but my app crashed saying that I can't observe forever on a background thread. Would you know how to go around it?

Answer (score 0):

The idea in MVVM is to observe from view if you are doing an action that you want to be sure is finished do not wrap it in a livedata. Basically you don't need any life cycle aware component. Your query should return list of photos without any need to observe it. I mean in your dao if you don't wrap data in a livedata you don't need to observe anything and getAllPhotos return photos. You can do this kind of thing anywhrere just do everything from background, in a thread or something. For both kind of designs you can have 1 livedata wraped method in dao and 1 method without livedata for jobs that need to be done serially.

Update: put your code in a background thread:

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
val allPhotosStatic = photoDao.getAllPhotosStatic()
                        for (file in it) {
                val image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromFilePath(application, Uri.parse(file.uri))

                detector.detectInImage(image).addOnSuccessListener { list ->
                    if (list.isNotEmpty()) {
                        file.hasFaces = 1
                        repo.update(file)
                    } else {
                        file.hasFaces = 2
                        repo.update(file)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

or:

```
    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
val allPhotosStatic = photoDao.getAllPhotosStatic()
                        for (file in it) {
                val image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromFilePath(application, Uri.parse(file.uri))

                detector.detectInImage(image).addOnSuccessListener { list ->
                    if (list.isNotEmpty()) {
                        file.hasFaces = 1
                        repo.update(file)
                    } else {
                        file.hasFaces = 2
                        repo.update(file)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you Sina. So I've tries implementing your suggestion, but as soon as I implement the call from my repository to the Dao, for the query I need as a non-LiveData list, my app crashes. I''ve added more info into my edited question.

Comment: It seems the error is due to a call from main thread. Put your code in a new thread. I've just updated my answer.